# How can I make this div slide across half of the screen?

Tags: javascript, animation, dom

I am trying to build some responsive javascript code that will make this div slide across half of the screen.

I am able to make this div move across 'x' amount of the screen but I am unsure how to make it responsive.. I would love some guidance! I think my main problem is I don't know what 'units' javascript moves in..

Any help would be greatly appreciate. I am still trying to learn!

```js
var div = document.getElementById("slidingDiv");
div.style.position = "absolute";
var left = document.body.offsetWidth;
div.style.left = left + "px";
var gap = 3;
var timer = window.setInterval(function() {
  div.style.left = left + "px";
  if (left - gap < 40) {
    left = 0;
  } else {
    left -= gap;
  }
  if (left == 0) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, 1);
```

```html
<div id="slidingDiv">Move me!</div>
```

Looking at the "if (left - gap < 40)..... I want the '40' to basically be half the width of the screen.

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe just with `let halfWidth = parseInt(window.innerWidth / 2);` ?

Comment: yep, you're right. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need JavaScript for this. Instead, use CSS animations.

```css
/* Animation to have any absolute element go from the right to left center */
@keyframes slide-from-left {
  from {
    left: 100%;
  }
  to {
    left: 50%;
  }
}

/* Element to be moved. Must have position: absolute */
.slide-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  animation-name: slide-from-left;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="slide-left">Fancy div!</div>
</body>
```

**Edit:**

It looks like you want it to run on scroll. This is not currently possible with CSS 3, so you will have to use partial JavaScript. If JavaScript is disabled, the element should default to the center.

```js
// Sets element to right by default if JavaScript enabled, otherwise element is by default animated
document.getElementsByClassName("element")[0].className = "element hide-to-right";

// If scroll and scroll height is more than 50% of window height, add the slide-in class, making the div move
window.onscroll = function() {
  if (window.scrollY > window.innerHeight/2) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("element")[0].className = "element slide-in";
  }
}
```

```css
@keyframes slide-from-left {
  from {
    left: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  to {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
.element {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.hide-to-right {
  left: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.slide-in {
  animation-name: slide-from-left;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="height:100vh;">Content, scroll down...</div>
  <div class="element">Fancy div!</div>
  <div style="height:100vh;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey this is awesome too :) didnt know you could do this with css animation. In terms of using this for a real project.. Is it better to use css animaton or javascript that still shows the image in the browser if js is disabled? Both in terms of page speed and cross browser compatibility?? I'd love some insight!

Comment: p.s. I would still need to use javascript anyways to display this on scroll...

Comment: I would use a CSS animation because it utilizes the clients hardware acceleration instead of their CPU which can be slower. Additionally, 0.2% of browsers don't have JavaScript or have it disabled for "security", so it is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: I updated my answer to include code on scroll that works with or without JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You can use (window.innerWidth / 2) to get half the width of the screen.

Comment: Wow, that worked. Thanks so much. I obviously need to dig more into syntax for DOM manipulation :) I really appreciate your answer!